# GlassFish cannot be installed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

Tried to install glassfish4 server in eclipse oxygen. Everything is ok except that it cannot recognize the jdk. Its saying JDK required instead of JRE. I have given the right path of my JDK, but still its saying that its JRE. When I am giving "javac -version" command in the command prompt its correctly showing java version "9.0.4".  Please help.

Comment: Glassfish 4 supports java 7 so eventually you could run it with java8 but not 9.

Comment: If I install glass fish 5 , can it be used with java9?

Answer (score 0):

No version of GlassFish supports JDK 9 at the moment. You will need to downgrade to JDK 8.

Additionally, the GlassFish Tools for Eclipse IDE have not been formally updated to support GlassFish 5 yet. With the move of Java EE and GlassFish to the Eclipse foundation, this is likely to happen but it is hard to say when at this point.